# Gtranslate plugin add backslash before apostrophe

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using **Gtranslate** plugin for a client website and translating some words using the apostrophe I found that the plugin add a backslash before it:

**Hello I/'m going to dinner...**

How can I remove the backslash before apostrophe?

There is a php fix that I can add to the plugin or should I use a javascript solution?

And can you can help me to find a good way to do it in both case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression in Javascript can remove all backslashes, but there might be cases where the string really means to use a backslash. Then you would need a more specific change, from `\'` to `'`

http://jsfiddle.net/scx8t/

```
​s = "I\\'m Bob and you\\'re Jane\\\\'s mother";
document.write("before: " + s + "<br>")

s = s.replace(/\\/g, "")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
​document.write("after: " + s);
```

To specifically replace \' write `s.replace(/\\'/g, "'")`

For this slash `/` you would write `s.replace(/\//g, "")`​​​​​​​​, for both, `s.replace(/[\/\\]/g, "")`

*EDIT*: For this application a PHP `preg_replace` appears more appropriate. I just don't have a PHP running right now so I wrote Javascript :P Here's what it should look like:

```
<?php
$str = 'I\\\'m Joe, you\\\'re Sara';
$str = preg_replace('/\\/', '', $str);
// I'm not sure if the g goes at the end of the pattern to replace all.
echo $str;
?>
```

*NOTE* `/\\/` might need to be `/\\/g`. I'm not familiar with PHP.

[from here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) Example #4 Strip whitespace

Comment: You got me there, it would be easier to clean the strings before they appear embedded in the HTML tags. There is `preg_replace` for PHP and I added a sample above that I hope is correct. (or someone nice comes along and corrects it). I mean, my idea was to traverse the DOM and apply the Javascript replace to every string I ran into. Not ideal. Much easier to remove the backslashes in order as they are placed to HTML.

Comment: @AndreaTurri Sorry it took a while. I updated the answer so you may try a PHP solution.

Comment: The problem is that I've many strings, all dynamics. So I need a complete fix for each of them.
Maybe a javascript solution could be faster, because I'm not familiar with php. But I can not solve the issue using your regex.. I was trying something similar without good results.

Comment: @AndreaTurri OK, let me think a bit harder. Would you explain the logic of your application? Might help with a direction for a solution.

Comment: It's simple, I have lot of text written in german lang and copywriter is traslating it in english and she's using lot of "I'm", "We're", etc... it result in this error and it appear "I/'m", "We/'re", etc... I need to remove the slash before apostrophe.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give details? For example, does she use Microsoft Word and that goes into your webpage? Or does she fill in a web form?There must be a source from where these backslashes appear.

Comment: She use Gtranslate. It's a plugin that let translate pages.

Comment: @AndreaTurri Dumb of me not to realize it since it's in the title. I'll see what this plugin is about.

Comment: @AndreaTurri I have a solution but I think it is dangerous (my safer alternative of traversing the DOM is not working). The idea is to take all the content inside `<body>` and remove all backslashes, even inside other tags I think. It might break directory locations, for example. You have to be sure to search your generated HTML files that the only place backslashes appear are next to the apostrophes. This is the update: http://jsfiddle.net/scx8t/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/scx8t/5/ this actually shows how it works inside a single file

Comment: / That's perfect, I've understand where I was wrong in coding, I was near to the solution. Thanks for your help.